# Browser/postman not wait for @Async Spring MVC Controller Response?

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I am using SpringMVC with AngularJS. I made one controller which I want to call asynchronously but when I send POST request from Postman for testing it will return immediately without waiting for the response. I also tried Callable, Executor but nothing works. When I remove @Async it works fine. Can any one please help?

```
@RestController
public class GenServiceController {

@Autowired
private GenService service;

@RequestMapping(value = "/log", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ExceptionHandler(ForbiddenErrorCodeException.class)
@ResponseBody
@Async
public DeferredResult<CustomResponse> log(@RequestBody TestInfo testInfo, 
                            @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String accessToken) throws ForbiddenErrorCodeException {

    String decodedAccessToken = null;
    CustomResponse customResponse = null;
    final DeferredResult<LogResponse> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();
    if (!Utils.isNullOrTrimEmpty(accessToken)) {
        accessToken = accessToken.replaceFirst("Basic" + " ", "");
        decodedAccessToken = Utils.decodeBase64(accessToken);
        final StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(decodedAccessToken, ":");
        final String token = tokenizer.nextToken();

        if (!service.isTokenExists(token)) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Token");
        } else {
            response = service.sendMessages(testInfo);
            if (response != null) {
                deferredResult.setResult(response);
            }
        }
    }
    return deferredResult;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to annotate your method with `Async` -- it doesn't make sense in your scenario. Just return either a `DeferredResult<CustomResponse>` or a `Callable<CustomResponse>`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. When we can use @Async then?

Comment: Not on a Controller. You can use it for example on your Service layer classes.